# Passing additional parameter to Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to pass additional parameter to Mongoose `findOne` query.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    SomeCollection.findOne({name: 'xxx' + i}, function (err, document) {
        if (document) {
            console.log('aaa' + i + document.somefield);  
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I am using `i` variable value in a `findOne` callback, since it is run in different thread I want to pass it to `findOne` method.

How can I do it?

Comment: why you use for loop outside instead using it inside `if(document){}` ?

Comment: It was just a pseudo code. Changed it to make my point more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're using node.js 4.x or above, you can effectively create a new scope per iteration by using [`let`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#let-declarations) instead of `var` in your `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    SomeCollection.findOne({name: 'xxx' + i}, function (err, document) {
        if (document) {
            // i will have the same value from the time of the findOne call
            console.log('aaa' + i + document.somefield);  
        }
    });
}
```